# When to run "sudo apt update" and when "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade"?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

As far as I remember, I always run `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update` before installing a new package.

When should I run **both `update` and `upgrade`** like this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available packages.

You run `sudo apt upgrade` to upgrade all installed packages.

Obviously you always run `update` before `upgrade` to use the latest list.

Comment: So, `sudo apt update` only prepares a list of upgradeable packages?

Comment: It downloads the latest list and compares with the installed package versions? Nothing else. You are correct. If you plan to install a new package, you need to get the list. Otherwise it may be not found.

Answer (score 5):

The `... update` part updates the library of available packages, so that your system knows what is available, and can compare them to what is installed.

The `... upgrade` fetches the packages from the repositories, and installed or 'upgrades' the packages.

Presumably you would only need the `... upgrade` if there were packages to upgrade, however if there are no upgradeable packages, `apt` exits without error.

Answer (score 3):

I think the man page explains it well:

```
   update (apt-get(8))
       update is used to download package information from all configured
       sources. Other commands operate on this data to e.g. perform
       package upgrades or search in and display details about all
       packages available for installation.

   upgrade (apt-get(8))
       upgrade is used to install available upgrades of all packages
       currently installed on the system from the sources configured via
       sources.list(5). New packages will be installed if required to
       satisfy dependencies, but existing packages will never be removed.
       If an upgrade for a package requires the remove of an installed
       package the upgrade for this package isn't performed.
```

So depending on your needs, you would want to use `update` or `upgrade` or both. Be aware that upgrading packages could bring some difficulties on it's own.

Comment: I'm trying to undestand it. Update prepares a list of new versions of packages, but doesn't install them. Upgrade installs the new versions.

Comment: `update` updates the information from the repositories, not necessarely the *newer* packages. For example if you want to install package_x, you may need to `update` first, so the package is available, after adding some entry to `sources.list`. Later you may want to `upgrade` package_x if there's a new version available.

Comment: *but doesn't install them*|*Upgrade installs the new versions* that's correct

Comment: In all cases of installation of a new package, I was running `apt update` then `apt install`, and NOT `apt upgrade`. That means that none of the upgradable packages were upgraded